# Why does *.* in regex return undefined

Tags: javascript, regex

At least, in Javascript, tested on both Chrome and Node.js:

```
new RegExp(/foo(optional)*boo/).exec('foooptionalboo')
```

Will match the `optional` in parentheses:

```
[ 'foooptionalboo',
'optional',
index: 0,
input: 'foooptionalboo' ]
```

But if you want there to be something in between the `optional`:

```
new RegExp(/foo.*(optional)*.*boo/).exec('foooptionalboo')
```

Then the `optional` is not found:

```
[ 'foooptionalboo',
'optional',
index: 0,
input: 'foooptionalboo' ]
```

Why is this?

Comment: `foo(?:(?!optional).)*(optional)*.*boo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with Quentin's answer is that `.*?` followed with an optional greedy subpattern `(optional)?` **and** a greedy dot matching pattern `.*` works in such a way that the `.*?` only matches the empty string, and `.*` takes up the whole rest of the string.

**Why does it happen?** Because lazy subpatterns that can match an empty string (and it will always match here since it can match an empty string) work so: once the lazy subpattern matches, other subpatterns to the right are tried, and if a match is found, the lazy subpattern is not re-tried.
[image]

To really grab an optional part, either use a specific pattern where no `.*` appears after the optional part, or (to make it more generic) use a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
foo(?:(?!optional).)*(optional)*.*boo
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fS5qU5/2)

The `(?:(?!optional).)*` is the tempered greedy token that matches any text up to the first `optional` substring.

Answer (score 5):

The `.*` matches `optional` before `(optional)*` has a chance to.

Make it non-greedy (with a `?`) so it won't match if the thing following it will.

```
/foo.*?(optional)*.*boo/.exec("foooptionalboo")
```

Comment: That seems to work for `foooptionalboo`, but not if I actually want to allow characters in between the words, such as `foo optional boo`